# C# generic collections: using them in public properties without making the class generic

Tags: c#, generics

Non generic collections are often presented as obsolete, a sort of a legacy of the first implementation of the C# collection framework.
If that was the case, I should have a way to solve the following, very common problem with a generic solution.

This is a simple class that writes on the Console the items of the collection it receives.

```
public class ValuesWriter
{
    public IList Values { get; set; }

    public void Write()
    {
        foreach(object o in Values)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(o.ToString());
        }
    }

}
```

The usage is this:

```
List<string> stringValues = new List<string>() { "first", "second", "third" };
ValuesWriter w1 = new ValuesWriter() { Values = stringValues };
w1.Write();

List<int> intValues = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
ValuesWriter w2 = new ValuesWriter() { Values = intValues };
w2.Write();
```

#### Question

Is there another efficient way to handle a generic collection as a public property without turning my class into a generic class itself?

Comment: Please focus on *one* question, there are at least 4 different questions here and the title doesn't even make sense. `System` types are completely unrelated to c#, they are part of the .NET BCL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything and everything you can do with a non-generic collection you can do with the generic `List<Object>` or equivalent.

But don't.

For the more specific example, you can have a generic method in a non-generic class, and this is a better pattern:

```
public class ValuesWriter
{
    public static void WriteCollection<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        foreach(T item in items)
        {
            //no need for ToString()... WriteLine has an overload for Object
            Console.WriteLine(item); 
        }
    }
}

ValuesWriter.WriteCollection(stringValues);
List<int> intValues = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
ValuesWriter.WriteCollection(intValues);
```

Notice the generic method can infer the type it needs, so we can still call it like a normal method.

But I'll give you benefit of the doubt that this is a simplified example, and you have a need to build an instance that keeps the collection as a member not explained in the question. In that case, yes, we need a generic class. But what's the problem with that?

```
public class ValuesWriter<T>
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Values {get; set;}

    public ValuesWriter<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        this.Values = items;
    }

    public void Write()
    {
        foreach(T item in Values) Console.WriteLine(item); 
    }
}


var w1 = new ValuesWriter<string>(stringValues);
w1.Write();

List<int> intValues = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
var w2 = new ValuesWriter<int>(intValues);
w2.Write();
```

As for the side question, the reason is `List<object>` is not `List<int>`. You can assign an integer to an object reference, but once you start looking at collections things are picker. Just because `TypeB` inherits `TypeA`, it doesn't mean `GenericType<TypeB>` inherits `GenericType<TypeA>`. You don't get that automatically.

Sometimes what you really need to do in this situation is define a new **interface** type, and have all the of types you need to worry about implement this interface.

Comment: A type parameter may or may not belong to the class interface, you should not be forced to add it just because you have generic collections into the class interface. E.G. I would like to have a class that can handle Collections of Animals, that are collection of Dogs and collections of Ducks. The class knows how to treat Dogs and Ducks and handles it at runtime, so it doesn't require that you bind the class instance to one type or the other via a type parameter (in my example, .ToString() worked for both types).

Comment: @AgostinoX That sounds like you're using inheritance in a situation where you should be using composition instead.